# Is this SAR-related question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wonder where is the best place to ask this question. It is about SAR systems that is used in remote sensing but involves [signal processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

The only reason that makes me dubious about asking this question in the [signal processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) community is that maybe they are not familiar at all with the structure of SLC, GRD or MLC files.

[What does it mean to store cross products in SAR product data file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160729/what-does-it-mean-to-store-cross-products-in-sar-product-data-file)

Comment: I edited the title for a more positive impression of this question. I think it is on topic. I also think that after the recent discussion this community had about making clear we welcome other GIS areas such as RS, Photogrammetry, etc, there is no need to post here asking if such types of subjects are on topic or not. I would only post if a question about radar gets closed as off-topic (then, I'd ask here for more explanation). Regarding the best SE site to post; make sure it is also on-topic in that other site if you decide asking the question to be migrated (don't cross post it).